# Visual Studio's Folder View context menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 it is possible to switch Solution Explorer into a folder view by pressing the Solutions and Folders button on the toolbar at the top. I want to add something to the context menu of the root folder in this view. I've been into 'Customize...' switched to the 'Commands' tab and am looking in the list under the 'Context Menu:' dropdown, but I can't figure out which menu it is?

Does anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Other Context Menus | Workspace Context Menu` works for items in Solution Explorer's Folder View.  I don't know how you could limit an entry to just the root folder.

[image]